# How to know if the observer function have executed after an event?

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, debug

I am trying to observe an event. How can I debug or know if the observer function has been called?
I am using the event "checkout_cart_add_product_complete" and trying to do something simple when a product is added to the cart. But nothing happen when I add the product. I would like to know if the function was reached.
My "events.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_cart_add_product_complete">
    <observer name="send_order_tracy" instance="Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer\SendOrderToTracy"/>
</event>
</config>
```

My observer class:

```
<?php

namespace Tracy\ShippingMethod\Observer;

class SendOrderToTracy implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        debug_to_console("por la chuchaaa");
        //die('Observer Is called!');
    }

    function debug_to_console( $data ) {
        $output = $data;
        if ( is_array( $output ) )
            $output = implode( ',', $output);

        echo "<script>console.log( 'Debug Objects: " . $output . "' );</script>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code in your observer `execute` function like this-

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP.'/var/log/test.log'); // creates new log file named test.log in var/log folder
       $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
       $logger->addWriter($writer);
       $logger->info("observer called"); // this will be print in test.log file

    }
```

For newer Magento2.4.X version :

```
$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info("---my custome message-----" );
```

it will create new log file named 'test.log' in `var/log` folder and it will print string 'observer called' in it if observer is called.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank, I will try this. By the way, with any change is necessary to compile using: "php bin/magento setup:di:compile"? because this process take a lot of minutes in my enviroment. –

Comment: not for all changes in observer..just need to clear cache ..

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat For Magento 1 how can i do that?

Comment: @zus, you can use  `Mage::log('text', null, "log.log", true);` in magento1

Comment: How to do what event trigger if observer executed and print triggered event in log file

Comment: For Magento 2.4 versions 

$writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend_Log();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

Answer (score 1):

try to add this script on your `debug_to_console` function :

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class)->debug('observer function called');
```

it will write message to your log file, I don't remember what is exactly but you can find in these log file `debug.log`, `system.log` or `exception.log` just check one of them.

**note :** `objectManager` is not recommended way, but I write this just to debug and make sure your observer called. After you found it works just deleted this code part

Comment: Thanks @mrfizh, I will try this. 
By the way, with any change is necessary to compile using: "php bin/magento setup:di:compile"? because this process take a lot of minutes in my enviroment.

Comment: I think you don't need to do `di:compile`, it should be just executed since you already do `di:compile` after define the observer at the first time